# How can I adjust the ExpressionEngine search rate limit?

Tags: expressionengine

I have added a search functionality to my ExpressionEngine site, using the standard [Search Module](http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/modules/search/index.html) tags. However, I occasionally run into this error message:

*You are only allowed to search every 15 seconds.*

This only seems to happen when I'm logged out.

I want to decrease the time required between searches. How can I adjust this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's a per-group setting (hence why it's only happening when you're logged out). The default for logged out members (the *Guests* group) is 15 seconds.

You can adjust this value for each group under *Members* > *Member Groups* > *Edit Group* in the control panel.